# Structuring SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

Help structuring SQL query:

```
Select Distinct ilc.itemnum, id.itemname, statename, realname
From hsi.itemlc ilc
INNER JOIN hsi.itemdata id ON
id.itemnum = ilc.itemnum
INNER JOIN hsi.lcstate lcs ON
lcs.statenum = ilc.statenum
INNER JOIN hsi.useraccount ua ON
ua.usernum = id.usernum
INNER JOIN hsi.wftransactionlog wft ON
id.itemnum = wft.itemnum

Where ilc.statenum not in ('143','144')
and ilc.lcnum in ('101','252')
and ilc.status <> 16
```

On my last join to hsi.wftransactionlog I only want to pull the max wft.logdate when id.itemnum = wft.itemnum.   What is the best way to accomplish this?  There are several "itemnum's" in  hsi.wftransactionlog but I only want to grab the matches in the table on the latest wft.logdate.

Please let me know if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CROSS APPLY with a sub query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ilc.itemnum, id.itemname, statename, realname
From hsi.itemlc ilc
INNER JOIN hsi.itemdata id ON
id.itemnum = ilc.itemnum
INNER JOIN hsi.lcstate lcs ON
lcs.statenum = ilc.statenum
INNER JOIN hsi.useraccount ua ON
ua.usernum = id.usernum
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT MAX(logdate) AS logdate
              FROM hsi.wftransactionlog wft
              WHERE id.itemnum = wft.itemnum
            ) wft1
```

Comment: Getting error:  No column name was specified for column 1 of 'wft1'.

Comment: Sorry forgot to alias the column inside the sub query. Have edited it now, can you try again please?

Comment: Appears to be working.  Correct number of results.  Going to check a few.

Comment: Nice one mate :)

Comment: Looked at a few.  It isn't grabbing the correct max date :/.  The wft.itemnum has different user names per itemnum.  This currently isn't grabbing the user with the most recent logdate.  My brain hurts.

Comment: Think I need to see some example data. The sub query should grab the latest date for the linked column 'wft.itemnum'. If your joins are correct between the tables it should work.

Comment: This doesn't work obviously but this is what I am trying to accomplish...


   `SELECT * username`
   `FROM [OnBaseP].[hsi].[wftransactionlog]`
   `WHERE logdate = MAX(logdate)`

Comment: Yeh, I need to go back and double check my joins I think.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a shot in the dark without any example data to test on, but using a subquery might work for you.

```
Select Distinct ilc.itemnum, id.itemname, statename, realname,
        ( select max(wft.logdate)
            hsi.wftransactionlog wft
            where wft.itemnum = id.itemnum
        ) as logdate
    From hsi.itemlc ilc
    INNER JOIN hsi.itemdata id ON id.itemnum = ilc.itemnum
    INNER JOIN hsi.lcstate lcs ON lcs.statenum = ilc.statenum
    INNER JOIN hsi.useraccount ua ON ua.usernum = id.usernum
    Where ilc.statenum not in ('143','144')
        and ilc.lcnum in ('101','252')
        and ilc.status <> 16
```